# How to resolve unmet peer depenency error with eslint

Tags: npm-install, react-starter-kit

I'm using the react starter kit

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

I cloned and did an `npm install` and I see in the node_modules folder that it installed eslint @2.2

but I still get the error

`npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@<2.3.0, required by babel-eslint@5.0.4`

The package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "core-js": "^2.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "csscomb": "^3.1.8",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "gaze": "^0.5.2",
    "git-repository": "^0.1.1",
    "glob": "^7.0.0",
    "jade-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.8.2",
    "jscs": "^2.10.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^5.0.18",
    "postcss-import": "^8.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.6",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.2",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.2",
    "replace": "^0.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.8.1",
    "webpack-middleware": "^1.4.0"
```

And here are the packages with `npm ls --depth 0`

```
├── assets-webpack-plugin@3.5.0
├── autoprefixer@6.5.3
├── babel-cli@6.18.0
├── babel-eslint@5.0.4
├── babel-loader@6.2.9
├── babel-plugin-react-transform@2.0.2
├── babel-plugin-transform-runtime@6.15.0
├── babel-polyfill@6.6.1
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.18.0
├── babel-preset-react@6.16.0
├── babel-preset-stage-0@6.16.0
├── babel-runtime@6.6.1
├── bluebird@3.3.3
├── body-parser@1.15.0
├── browser-sync@2.18.2
├── classnames@2.2.3
├── cookie-parser@1.4.1
├── core-js@2.4.1
├── css-loader@0.23.1
├── csscomb@3.1.8
├── del@2.2.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@2.13.1
├── eslint-config-airbnb@6.2.0
├── eslint-loader@1.6.1
├── eslint-plugin-react@4.3.0
├── eventemitter3@1.1.1
├── express@4.13.4
├── express-graphql@0.4.9
├── express-jwt@3.3.0
├── extend@3.0.0
├── fastclick@1.0.6
├── fbjs@0.7.2
├── file-loader@0.8.5
├── front-matter@2.0.6
├── gaze@0.5.2
├── git-repository@0.1.4
├── glob@7.1.1
├── graphiql@0.5.0
├── graphql@0.4.18
├── history@2.0.0
├── isomorphic-style-loader@0.0.10
├── jade@1.11.0
├── jade-loader@0.8.0
├── jest-cli@0.8.2
├── jscs@2.11.0
├── json-loader@0.5.4
├── jsonwebtoken@5.7.0
├── markdown-it@6.0.0
├── mkdirp@0.5.1
├── ncp@2.0.0
├── node-fetch@1.3.3
├── normalize.css@3.0.3
├── passport@0.3.2
├── passport-facebook@2.1.0
├── pg@4.5.1
├── postcss@5.2.6
├── postcss-import@8.2.0
├── postcss-loader@0.8.2
├── postcss-scss@0.1.9
├── precss@1.4.0
├── pretty-error@2.0.0
├── raw-loader@0.5.1
├── react@0.14.7
├── react-dom@0.14.7
├── react-routing@0.0.7
├── react-transform-catch-errors@1.0.2
├── react-transform-hmr@1.0.4
├── redbox-react@1.3.3
├── replace@0.3.0
├── source-map-support@0.4.0
├── url-loader@0.5.7
├── webpack@1.14.0
├── webpack-hot-middleware@2.13.2
├── webpack-middleware@1.5.1
└── whatwg-fetch@0.11.0
```